# How to separate the query and the train image from the Mat object returned from DrawMatches() method

Tags: opencv, pattern-matching, video-capture, feature-detection, feature-descriptor

I am trying to detect an object in a video. i am using SURF as feature detection and descriptor extractor, and BRUTFORCE as matcher. i tested my work with faces, i captured a picture of me and when i run the camera and direct it toward me, my face gets detected and a rectangle is drawn around it. i tried to make another test, i captured an image of my mouse and resized it, and when i run the cam, it is not getting detected

the problems i am facing are:

1-is the size of the query/object image matters in such cases,? i am asking this question because the image i captured of my self is bigger than the one of the mouse, and the face is getting detected and the mouse not.

2-regardless of which image i am using as a query/object iamge, how to display camera preview of only the train/scene image without the query/object image. i am asking this question because, what i am getting is something as shown in the below posted images, while what i want to do is something as it is shown [here](http://robocv.blogspot.de/2012/02/real-time-object-detection-in-opencv.html), i checked the code in that link, it is in C++ but i followed the same thing and also the tutorial uses 'drawMatches' method which has a peer in java which is `Features2D.DrawMatches()` and both of them returns a Mat object with the query/object image on the left side and the train/scene image on the right side as also shown in the image i posted below.

what i want to do is, to display on the the camera output without the query/object image, i want the area designated for the camera output is to show only the train/scene image captured from the camera.

please let me know how to solve this issues, i want to do something as shown in the tutorial  i cited in the link.

[image: img_1]
[image: img_2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - size matters but in your case, I think the most crucial problem is "textureness". SURF detect the interest points where the "texture gradient" is strong. In the case of your mouse, the gradient is mainly smooth, except aroud the logo (fujitsu), the button and at the border of the image. In the tutorial you point to, you notice it uses a very textured object to demonstrate the effect.

2 - to the best of my knowledge, there is fully automatic method to do what you want, but it can be done with a few steps. Basically, you must determine the surrounding box of your object then draw it. To draw, the easier is to use cv::rectangle but you can be more precise with four (or more....) cv::line. To determine the surrounding box, you can estimate the extreme points among the filtered matches.

Good luck!